# Offset in split text content

Tags: code-golf, text-processing

You will be given an ASCII text. This text may have zero, one or many appearances of a split a character (let's assume it will be the space character )
You will also be given an offset integer value (zero based) anywhere between zero and the length of the text.

You should calculate the relative offset inside the one split text, which contains the absolute offset, as well as the index of that very split text.
If the given offset is at the split character the last split should have the offset

It's hard to describe (comments welcome), so here are some examples

```
text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
offset: 20

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
enter code here
--------------------^
000000000011111111112
012345678901234567890

Result: 2, 3
Explanation: If we split the text along the space characters, the split text, where the offset is in, is the fragment `sit` which is the 3rd split (count starts at zero) and the offset inside this fragment is 2  
sit
--^
012
```

Some more examples

```
Text                           Offset        Result
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     0             0, 0
^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     1             1, 0
-^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     2             2, 0
--^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     3             3, 0
---^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     4             4, 0
----^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     5             5, 0
-----^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     6             0, 1
------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     7             1, 1
-------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     8             2, 1
--------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     9             3, 1
---------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     10            4, 1
----------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     11            5, 1
-----------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     12            0, 2
------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     13            1, 2
-------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     14            2, 2
--------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     15            3, 2
---------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     16            4, 2
----------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     17            5, 2
-----------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     18            0, 3
------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     19            1, 3
-------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     20            2, 3
--------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     21            3, 3
---------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     22            0, 4
----------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     23            1, 4
-----------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     24            2, 4
------------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     25            3, 4
-------------------------^
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     26            4, 4
--------------------------^
```

Comment: If I am correctly interpreting your example, the second integer is the number of split characters in the first `offset` characters, the first is the character that is hit inside the chunk counted from its own origin? Do the two have anything in common?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I assume your thought on the second integer is correct. I don't understand your thought on the first character. And what do you mean by `Do the two have anything in common?`?

Comment: To me, the question appears to simply be two properties of a piece of text mangled together; I wanted to ask if there is any semantic connection between the two output integers.

Comment: You want to now the reason why I ask this? It's inspired by this question on SE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235774/text-area-getting-accurate-cursor-position-on-resize And I thought it would be an interesting question on CG

Comment: Can we use 1 indexed instead of 0 indexed

Comment: I'd prefer 0 but I'm not bound to it

Comment: "It's hard to describe (comments welcome)". This is why the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) exists. When you want to create challenges, first lay them in the sandbox and let other people help you refine it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html), 56 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(x:=a[:b].split(' '))and[len(x[-1]),len(x)-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldNLCoMwFIXheVcRnJiALb2xDyu4g@7AOoioVMiLmIJdfSpdwXF2Bv/oflz/jW9ny8qHNDWvpJXpB8VU0dd8rRvV1n13WryeI89ZLoSyQ6tHy9f2SJ0o/lNsM/kw28gnnj1dGA2b/fIxbHDaBbbMkSkzxqxgZyEOWElwKeGyhMsLXF7h8gaXd7is4PKBX34HEq5EOBPhToRDES5FOBXhVoRjEa4lcS2546dwLYlrSVxL4lpy00o/)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl  5, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
$_=substr$_,0,<>;/.* /;$_=$'=~y///c.$".y/ //
```

- `$_=substr$_,0,<>;` to extract first n (from nextline <>) characters of input `$_` and store in default argument.
- `/.* /` to match largest string ending with space
- `$_=$'=~y///c.$".y/ //` default argument `$_` (which will be printed `-p` option) is set with concatenation `.` of length of post-match : `$'=~y///c`, `$"` space (list argument delimiter when interpolated betwen double quotes), and `y/ //` number of spaces in current default argument.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NKm4pEglXsdAx8bOWl9PS0HfGiisom5bV6mvr5@sp6KkV6mvoK///79PflFqrkJmQXFprkJKfk5@kUJxZolCYm5qCZehARc@WUO8siZ4ZU3/5ReUZObnFf/XLcgBAA)

Comment: Oh wow! How very cryptic of you

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╓ò)♣*
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d69529052a&i=%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++0%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++1%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++2%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++3%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++4%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++5%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++6%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++7%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++8%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++9%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+10%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+11%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+12%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+13%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+14%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+15%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+16%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+17%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+18%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+19%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+20%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+21%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+22%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+23%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+24%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+25%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+26&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
(       trim string to length
j       split on spaces
N       remove last element from array and push separately
W       until the stack is empty...
  %P    pop element and print its length
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%28+++%09trim+string+to+length%0Aj+++%09split+on+spaces%0AN+++%09remove+last+element+from+array+and+push+separately%0AW+++%09until+the+stack+is+empty...%0A++%25P%09pop+element+and+print+its+length&i=%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++0%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++1%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++2%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++3%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++4%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++5%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++6%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++7%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++8%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22++9%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+10%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+11%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+12%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+13%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+14%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+15%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+16%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+17%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+18%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+19%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+20%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+21%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+22%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+23%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+24%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+25%0A%22Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%22+26&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
£ð¡¤gsg<‚
```

Port of [*@JonasAusevicius*'s Python 3.8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181801/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0OLDGw4tPLQkvTjd5lHDrP//ffKLUnMVMguKS3MVUvJz8osUijNLFBJzU0u4jAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oqenYJE97JYXEvBQFJXs/IOtR2yQgy9Pv/6HFhzccWnhoSXpxus2jhln/df775Bel5ipkFhSX5iqk5OfkFykUZ5YoJOamlgAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
£         # Only leave the first (implicit) input-integer amount of characters
          #  of the (implicit) string-input
 ð¡       # Split this by spaces
          # (Note: builtin `#` doesn't work here, because a string without spaces
          #  would not be wrapped in a list)
   ¤g     # Get the length of the last string in the list (without popping the list itself)
     sg<  # Swap to get the list again, and get it's length minus 1
        ‚ # Pair both integers (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Node.js), <del>75</del> <del>70</del> <del>69</del> <del>70</del> <del>68</del> 67 bytes

```
t=>o=>[o+~(s=t.substr(0,o)).lastIndexOf(' '),s.split(' ').length-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldO7CsJAEIXh3qdYbNxFs7jrLSKxFwQfQCyi2WhkkwmZUax89Xh5g1NOcfiLj7nnz5wvXdVK0lAR@jLrJdtStj3S@K05E8uPM0unpxMyxsacZdcU4XUo9UiNzIQtt7GS/2FjaK5yS9ypv1DDFIONdNWlHu6pC7WqWn7UqqBIneJKVF4HGRo9NWajkIH7DgbIwKOFGVqYo4UFWliihRVaSNHCGi24HzU0gKmdRxOwtZujCRjbLdEErO1SNAFze5Tb45@NcnuY26PcHub2P@7@Aw)

No space parameter, only hardcoded (+ 2 bytes)
-2 bytes thanks to inspiration from the [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181812/85356) by [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
-1 byte thanks to [zevee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70328/zevee)

Comment: `o-s.lastIndexOf(d)-1` can be `o+~s.lastIndexOf(d)` to save a byte ([here the relevant tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210)).

Comment: Also, you take the space as input, but all the others answers thus far hardcoded the space. So either the challenge should mention a third split-character is required as input, or this answer could also hardcode the space. Not sure which of the two you intended when you made the challenge?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I used a hardcoded space now

Comment: You can do `t=>o=>` instead of `(t,o)=>` to save a byte and then take input as `f(t)(o)`

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>((a=a.Substring(0,b).Split())[b=a.Length-1].Length,b);
```

8 bytes saved thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) and a further 3 bytes saved thanks to [Embodiment of Ignorance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84206/embodiment-of-ignorance)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldO9DoIwFIbh3atonNoEDaf@B2F0YnNwMA4Fq54ECqFl8OoRjBfgN7Rp05N3edLSL0rPw6l35fH@dqbmMvpe2IVITtu4VJaJh0gHk2ZFmklpUrM894UPHbunjKNCLc9txUEqdS3Gt9y6Z3gt6PY7jQPJkIjZ7NJxsDk7Kx9ynjedrQW3vq/FvamaTngOwtQ2zJWMlUr@n6ZxGohrKL7C4msovsHiWyi@w@J7KH7A4gSKgqSEmRKISpgqgayEuRIIS5gsgbQao9Xob8VoNUirMVoN0uqJdvgA)

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY69DoMwDIR3nsLqQiJ@ROeQLJU6sTF0qDoEGqglCCgxff0UWujg09n@znLrs9ZjuC62LT05tH369WgpZZusxZWCDmTQUjVSMaalzuul@eGsSBvO83oekFgMMb832/rf5pWxPb2y82N3Kx4ERNFbOyDj6aK9AQmnanJmBJz9MsJzGiYHHgn0aOgkom5y2zeAshCApTyC@811liQ8Arg5JFOhNaxjB8MZci7CBw)

Comment: Cut another 10 using dynamic and saving the extra split

Comment: Oh smart! I need to remember that.

Comment: 60 bytes: https://tio.run/##ldO9DoIwFIbh3atonNoEDaf@B2F0YnNwMA4Fq54ECqFl8OoRjBfgN7Rp05N3edLSL0rPw6l35fH@dqbmMvpe2IVITtu4VJaJh0gHk2ZFmklpUrM894UPHbunjKNCLc9txUEqdS3Gt9y6Z3gt6PY7jQPJkIjZ7NJxsDk7Kx9ynjedrQW3vq/FvamaTngOwtQ2zJWMlUr@n6ZxGohrKL7C4msovsHiWyi@w@J7KH7A4gSKgqSEmRKISpgqgayEuRIIS5gsgbQao9Xob8VoNUirMVoN0uqJdvgA

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 33 bytes

```
(1++/m),n-¯1↑(m←(m←n↑⎕)=' ')/⍳n←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5rGGpr6@dq6uTpHlpv@KhtokYuUA5M5AF5QMWatuoK6pr6j3o3AwUmAAX@A/X9T@MyNOdS98kvSs1VyCwoLs1VSMnPyS9SKM4sUUjMTS1RBwA)

1 Indexed

Prompts for index of character in full text string followed by string

Outputs index of character in nth substring and substring number

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>83</s> 75 bytes

```java
n->s->n+~(s=s.substring(0,n)).lastIndexOf(" ")+","+~-s.split(" ",-1).length
```

-8 bytes implicitly thanks to inspiration from [*@yunzen*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181809/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fY8xT8MwEIX3/IqTJ1tOrLLSJgsSUiUQAyMwuI3TXnHsKHepqFD714PTpivTnd69p/fdwR5tcai/x623RPBqMfxmAMSWcQuHdDUDozfNELaMMZjneVmtA7ud6/P/PO/cY9jlt1FV0EA5hqKiogr6IqkkQ8OGrle5yINSJlHwOtTu562RAoTSIhf6UiRj55EnKS8eks2FHe/HZZZYu2HjE@uMfIxYQ5vekLfWjy@wanoJ4CYAO@InSw5KEC@xdy1gR0MLdfSxB0IG2zoWy2umib3EwIDlYgm4Ku/hmUCqpGqtrt7UcCJ2rYkDmy51sQ/yHtACbKhBaNTi8ZOFboztOn@SqObl7lRqqj5n5/EP)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->s->                   // Method with integer & String parameters and String return-type
  n+~                    //  Return `n` minus 1, minus the following:
     (s=s.substring(0,n))//   Set `s` to the first `n` characters of input-String `s`
      .lastIndexOf(" ")  //   and get the index of the last space
  +","                   //  Appended with a comma-delimiter
     s.split(" ",        //  Split the new `s` by spaces
                 -1)     //  and keep empty trailing items
  +~- ... .length        //  And append the amount of items minus 1 to the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḣḲẈṪ,LƊ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of characters on the left and the 0-indexed index on the right which yields a list of integers, `[character, word]`, again 0-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//4bij4biy4bqI4bmqLEzGiv///0xvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0/zIy)**

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//4bij4biy4bqITCzhuarGiv///0xvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0/zIy) should return `[4, 4]` ([10-byte fix](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//4bijMDDCpuG4suG6iEws4bmqxor///9Mb3JlbSBpcHN1bSBkb2xvciBzaXQgYW1ldP8yMg)).

Comment: Thanks @EriktheOutgolfer if we go with 0-indexing it works out nicely for 7.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Takes input as `(offset)(string)`.

```javascript
n=>g=([c,...a],b=i=0)=>n--?g(a,b+!(i+=c!=' '||-i)):[i,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY9DoIwFADgnVM8WGjTnxAHB/XhBbwBYSilkBp4JS26iGevftP3NG@TbPTbriiMLk@YCdsZWWel1tr0ckCPDceWlLrPzMhBlMwLtCXWUB@H8pxfOi@HPk8hMgKE5goEN4TT@R8hOHwKABsohcXpJcyMJEyMOKseIboV/JZeK4xhCRGS38Gsbq84L775Bw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                 // n = desired offset in string
  g = (              // g = recursive function taking:
    [c, ...a],       //   c = current character; a[] = array of remaining characters
    b =              //   b = index of current block
    i = 0            //   i = current position within the current block
  ) =>               //
    n-- ?            // if we haven't reached the desired offset: 
      g(             //   do a recursive call to g:
        a,           //     pass the array of remaining characters
        b + !(       //     update b:
          i +=       //       update i:
            c != ' ' //         increment i if the current character is not a space
            || -i    //         or set i to zero if it is
        )            //     increment b if i was set to zero, or leave it unchanged otherwise
      )              //   end of recursive call
    :                // else:
      [i, b]         //   stop recursion and return [i, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 66 bytes

```
z=$(echo ${i:0:o});echo $z|sed 's/^.* //g'|wc -c;set -- $z;echo $#
```

1-indexed. `$i` contains the input, and `$o` contains the offset

Explanation:

```
z=$(echo ${LDS:0:o});          # delete the rest of the word
echo $z|sed 's/^.* //g'|wc -c; # remove anything up to the last word, and count what's left.
set -- $z;echo $#              # find the number of words after the stuff after the offset is deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
≔⪪…ＳＮ θＩ⟦Ｌ⊟θＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYs9C8IwFAD3/opHpxdQKK6dpJNQpNBRHGIMSSDfeRH89TGKy8HBndA8i8Bta@dSjPK4R2sIl7ewctEh4sXHSjtl4xWyA/z0Wt1DZmTdRxg7E5uHrSd95IXwtkqvSOPW//St/p7YnbG5tTVk6cDEUh08gw0ZiiHgTtJwmtrxZT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪…ＳＮ θ
```

Truncate the input string to the given length and split on spaces.

```
Ｉ⟦Ｌ⊟θＬθ
```

Extract the last string and take its length, then take the number of remaining strings, cast both lengths to string and implicitly print them on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 50 bytes

```
^.+
$*
^(1)*¶((?<-1>.)*).*
$2
^(.*? )*(.*)
$.2,$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/Tk@bS0WLK07DUFPr0DYNDXsbXUM7PU0tTT0tLhUjoLielr2CphaQ0uRS0TPSUVE2/P/fyIDLJ78oNVchs6C4NFchJT8nv0ihOLNEITE3tQQA) Takes input in the order offset, string. Explanation:

```
^.+
$*
```

Convert the offset to unary.

```
^(1)*¶((?<-1>.)*).*
$2
```

Truncate the string to the given length. This uses .NET's balancing groups to count the same number of characters in each string.

```
^(.*? )*(.*)
$.2,$#1
```

Count the number of spaces and the number of characters after the last space and output them in decimal in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>53</s> 48 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{t=s[0,n];[n-t[/.* |^/].size,t.count(" ")]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEADAu6/YcGoN3TYevBj6An9AaFIrjSQCDbscbPHt6Nwn5cenrqp2I8lwsCI9yGBuOnSsezxDmXqD5HYrGZeYAzcCRGu@lZS4x2Q9uI2yh2d8xwTkGGZvWZyaAfFybdHOy@sormywapLuH38)